# How to build a WDM driver in WDK?

Tags: wdk, wdm

I want to build a WDM driver in the latest WDK. What's the difference between the sources file for WDM and WDF? How can I specify the build taget as WDM instead of WDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KMDF is just a wrapper library around WDM, so a SOURCES file with no references to KMDF build a WDM driver. Usually the only reference to KMDF in a SOURCES file is:

KMDF_VERSION_MAJOR=1

See the WDK documentation and samples for more info.

-scott